# Creating a GWT Wrapper for the JQuery UI Slider with UiBinder

Tags: java, jquery, gwt

I need to reproduce the example on the link http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/gwt-slider/ 
The SliderExample use div on the html. In my case i need to use UIBinder like:

```
<g:HTMLPanel height="100%" ui:field="sliderPanel" >
   <g:Label ui:field="labelSlider">Width:</g:Label>
   <s:Slider ui:field="sliderContainer"></s:Slider>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

My problem is when i trying to use the Slider on the .java application I obtain the error :

```
@UiField
Label labelSlider;
@UiField

.......

Slider sliderContainer;     
sliderContainer = new Slider("slider");
sliderContainer.setValue(10);
```

17:23:26.529 [ERROR] [test] Unable to load module entry point class be.lilab.sensport.client.Sensport (see associated exception for details)
java.lang.AssertionError: This UIObject's element is not set; you may be missing a call to either Composite.initWidget() or UIObject.setElement()
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject.getElement(UIObject.java:558)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel.addAndReplaceElement(HTMLPanel.java:206)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel.addAndReplaceElement(HTMLPanel.java:190)

Comment: Well, are you missing a call to Composite.initWidget() in (the constructor of) your widget's java class?

Comment: @Boris Brudnoy Yes of course